# Implementing Multinomial Logistic Classification

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, multinomial-distribution

I have a dataset that has probability labels instead of one-hot-encoded labels AND I'd like to keep it that way. The probabilities of each sample is information that I'd like to influence the loss function during backprop.

E.g. of dataset

| Sample (Movie) | Horror | Comedy | Drama | SciFy/Fantasy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aliens | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.0 | 0.5 |
| Dumb & Dumber | 0.0 | 0.8 | 0.2 | 0.0 |
| The Hobbit | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.5 |

Above you can see each movie is labeled corresponding to a category with a probability in each category. One-hot-encoding would *hard* classify Aliens as 100% SciFy/Fantasy, but there's value in knowing that this also belongs to horror and comedy too and in those exact proportions.

My usecase is a little more complicated than this as well. I'm not able to simply slap on scikit-learn's logistic regression model and call it a day. I'll need to use a timeseries neural network. I'm able to get *decent* results with my current model that converts everything to a one-hot-encoded classification, but I believe that it would perform significantly better if y_target utilized more *loose* class labels reflecting the probabilities in each of those labels.

I'm assuming that using those y_target probabilities will work just like any one-hot classification problem and that the loss function will reflect these softer labels, but I am unsure...

What I'm thinking is:

```
linear model output --> y_pred --> softmax << cross-entropy >> y_target
```

Essentially, use a linear output from the model. Then squash it down using softmax. Then calculate the loss with cross-entropy against y_target. y_pred and y_target will both have probability distributions and both will not be one-hot encoded.

Can this be done? and is it doing what I think it's doing? Has anyone seen any good examples of something similar?

Comment: Interesting question and a +1 from me, but I am concerned that you might be mixing up two ideas. It seems like your data are saying that *Aliens* is $30\%$ horror, $20\%$ comedy, and $50\%$ sci-fi/fantasy. What does that have to do with weights in backprop for a softmax neural network regression? // In a standard multinomial logistic regression, the output contains the probabilities of each class. This can be used to make a hard classification, but it does not have to be (and there are advantages to using the probability values instead of hard classifications).

Comment: This is obviously not something I've seen anywhere... I've dreamed up this approach. The reason why I think it'll impact cross-entropy loss is due to its formula.

H(P, Q) = – sum x in X P(x) * log(Q(x))

The probability distribution P(x) is multiplied by Q(x) for each class/label. So, in a typical 1-hot function, only one of these labels is ultimately calculated. My proposed approach would actually use the sum of the difference between prob distributions...

Comment: Focal Loss looks very promising. It's essentially cross-entropy with a weighting criteria. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02002.pdf Perhaps I can use hard 1-hot encoded y_targets, but use those percentages/probabilities as the weighting...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Yes, you can use cross entropy loss for comparing two vectors of continuous values. It's stated in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Definition) with supporting proofs:

> The situation for continuous distributions is analogous.